# Using Facebook Graph to get URL of Cover Photo

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I used to be able to get the URL of the cover photo using `me?fields=cover`
However, it does not seem to show the URL anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/changelog/version3.0

According to the changelog, the `cover` field is deprecated and will not work anymore in Apps with Graph API v3.0+.